# Android Find child view coordinates of rotated view super view

Tags: android, android-layout, rotatetransform

I have a Relative Layout that gets rotated using RotateAnimation.  In one corner of the layout there is a button.  Once the view is rotated, the button no longer receives the onTouch events.  I have tried a few things:

```
    float rotation = 90f;
    Rect closeButtonRect = new Rect();
    //close button reference in layout
    closeButton.getGlobalVisibleRect(closeButtonRect);
    RectF closeButtonRectf = new RectF(closeButtonRect);

    //1. get location of layout rectangle in parent
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);
    RectF rectf = new RectF(rect);

    //2 rotate the rectangle
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(rotation,rectf.centerX(), rectf.centerY());
    RectF destRect = new RectF();
    matrix.mapRect(destRect, closeButtonRectf);
    Log.d(TAG, "dest rect: " + destRect + " contains: " + destRect.contains(motionEvent.getRawX(), motionEvent.getRawY()));
```

Am I on the right track?  Do I have to translate all touch events from the superview to see if the touch is in the rectangle of rotated view?

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="300"
 android:layout_height="300">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bg_border"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_placement"/>

<ImageView
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/poof_animation"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/poof_view_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/poof_view_size"
    android:background="@drawable/poof_delete"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/closeButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_close_tool"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you find any solution ? i am facing same problem..